# How can I give self as an argument to a method in python?

Tags: python, methods, self

It was difficult to formulate the question, so here is the example I can't find a good solution for:

```
class bar(object):
    def foo_a(self):
        other_class.foo(self)    #This self should reference to bar
```

The point is, the compiler gives me an error, as he expects a parameter of type bar in `other_class.foo(self, bar_object)`, although I want to give him this parameter with self.

Comes this problem up only if you code in a bad style, or is there a good solution?

Comment: It is bad style. There are good philosophical reasons why you can't pass a class from a different inheritance path to a method.

Comment: Weird things will happen if you go this way if at all it works. If you want to control the object creation in some way use metaclasses. `foo()` might do horrible things to the `bar` object. You gotta be **real** careful.

Comment: I'm new to python and just curious, can you give me any references for those reasons? To me passing a full class to a method sounds very useful in some cases.

Comment: Can you tell me what `foo()` does?

Comment: I created this problem artificially, but the basic question came to me, when I was creating a decision tree and wanted to pass the full tree as a parameter to a `draw(tree)` function, which drew the whole tree for me. In the end I defined the `draw(tree)` function outside of a class.